# Encoding problems when passing parameters in url

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unicode, encoding

I'm writing a piece of Javascript that takes in the title of the current page, and sends it to a form in a Rails 3 app. If the title is something like

```
Review - “Episode 20”
```

then when I pass that title to my form:

```
http://localhost:3000/notes/myform?title=Review - “Episode 20”
```

the title appears in my form as

```
Review - �Episode 20�
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

```
console.log(encodeURI('Review - “Episode 20”')); 
// "Review%20-%20%E2%80%9CEpisode%2020%E2%80%9D"
```

I'm no Ruby pro, but I believe the Ruby way to decode this is `CGI::unescape()`

Answer (score 0):

Or use URI_escape:

```
enc_uri = URI.escape("http://example.com/?a=\11\15")
# => "http://example.com/?a=%09%0D"
```